Interpretation of the politics-religion-belief exemption regarding distribution of free printed matter in England?
English law, and specifically S1(4)(b) of Schedule 3A of the Environmental Protection Act 1990 as amended by the Clean Neighbourhoods and Environment Act 2005, is clear that a person can distribute free printed matter even in an area designated by a principal litter authority, such as a high street for example, without falling foul of either of the above-mentioned two Acts, so long as "the distribution is for political purposes or for the purposes of a religion or belief".
Let us say people wanted to distribute a periodical in this way. To be clear, they are not selling it or "trading" - they are handing it out for free.
Has there been any relevant case law in respect of the interpretation of the words "for political purposes or for the purposes of a religion or belief"?
If the editorial policy that tied the articles in the periodical together were something that might reasonably be expressed neither in political terms (whatever that means), nor in religious terms, but as the furtherance of the belief that (for example) "people shouldn't believe officials, managers, or The Man generally - and they're lying to us about X, Y, and Z", that's a belief, right, even if it isn't labelled as, say, "anarchist politics"? Indeed it would still be a belief even if all items in the broadsheet were literary and fictional.
Would for example a local council be likely to find much mileage if it were to reject this claim and prosecute distributors on the basis of the view that the S1(4)(b) exemption didn't apply? (Please disregard the issue of possible defamation. That's not what this question is about.)

"people shouldn't believe officials, managers, or The Man generally" sounds like a political conspiracy theory to me.

I think "belief" is intended to be more restrictive than general opinions -- the belief that Taylor Swift is the best musician of all time would fall into this.

@Barmar - It isn't. A political conspiracy theory is something like "LBJ ordered the JFK assassination" or "globalist big business pays scientists and statesmen to posit anthropogenic climate change". It's true you could reasonably say "people shouldn't believe officials, managers, or The Man generally" is a political belief, but the assumption in the question is that it wouldn't be couched as such in the publication. It might be framed as anti-political though.

@Barmar - Agreed about Taylor Swift. But why might that not be a reasonable argument on the publishers' side in litigation? This is assuming the publishers of the periodical weren't trying to sell tickets to this person's concerts.

Because in that case just about any publication would fall into this criteria. People Magazine publishes a "Sexiest Man Alive" issue, it's hard to imagine this belief is what they intended when drafting this law (assuming they gave it away for free rather than selling it).

Reductio ad absurdum isn't always sound though. But I take your point. After they mentioned religion, probably what they had in mind was non-religious ethical beliefs such as humanism, or the advocacy of e.g. vegetarianism. Unless there's case law to the contrary, I tend to think something that could be described in litigation as "many might call it philosophical anarchism being applied politically, but the publishers wouldn't" would count as a belief. Or for that matter, "many might call it political conspiracy theory, but the publishers wouldn't."

Without trying to Answer the actual Question, may I suggest that law is outrageous and should never have been proposed or considered, let alone passed?
How could 'littering' distinguish between free or paid-for material, or between political purposes or for the purposes of a religion or belief, and anything else?
How could a competent compiler of English law suggest any grammatical difference between 'political purposes' and 'the purposes of a religion or belief'?
That aside, I suggest the Grainger test, as explained below, is and will always remain largely unworkable.

The Grainger test
What is and is not a belief under English law has been litigated several times under the Equality Act, but I see no reason why the test here would be any different.
The Grainger test requires:
(i) The belief must be genuinely held.
(ii) It must be a belief and not an opinion or viewpoint based on the present state of information available.
(iii) It must be a belief as to a weighty and substantial aspect of human life and behaviour.
(iv) It must attain a certain level of cogency, seriousness, cohesion and importance.
(v) It must be worthy of respect in a democratic society, be not incompatible with human dignity and not conflict with the fundamental rights of others.
Subsequent cases have found the following to be beliefs: veganism, a belief in Scottish independence, gender critical beliefs, opposition to critical race theory with support for the attitude of Martin Luther King towards race, and anti-Zionist beliefs.
As expressed, the hypothetical “belief” might struggle on point iv: “cogency, seriousness, cohesion and importance”. But, if you can make a coherent argument as to what the expressed belief is, it should be fine.

Many thanks for this. It seems likely that the judgment in Grainger would indeed be referred to were the interpretation of "belief" in the context of the Acts mentioned in the question to be litigated. (But I have to note that Wikipedia is wrong to describe the belief in Grainger as the belief that "climate change exists". The judgment describes it as the belief that "we must urgently cut carbon emissions to avoid catastrophic climate change.")
